# Drag n Drop Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando fazer um Drag'n Drop puro com Javascript:

[Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Wagnerdabu/8vzj322e/8/)

Dois erros se não estou conseguindo solucionar:

1 - Quando arrasto o **Lista 2** ele sempre coloca o elemento para baixo do mouse e não em cima.

2 - Quando tento pegar o elemento pela *Class* não consigo.

**Obs:** Por *Id* ele consigo arrastar normalmente.

Answer (score 3):

Tenta isso:

No drag init tu coloca assim:

```
function drag_init(elem) {    
    selected = elem;    
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.closest('ul').offsetTop;
}
```

E o `document.getElementClassName` você substitui por:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.draggable').forEach(function(el) {
    el.onmousedown = function () { 
        drag_init(this);
        return false;
    };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8vzj322e/10/

Comment: Obrigado agora está indo por Class, mas agora quando clico no elemento  pela segunda vez ele vai alguns `px` para cima.

Comment: Percebi agora, vou tentar consertar!

Comment: Estou vendo aqui também.